# How can I boot GParted in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, gparted

I'm trying to increase the size of my boot partition because Arch keeps complaining about it.  I have GParted on a USB flash drive.  When I restart, there's no option to boot from the flash drive rather than the harddrive.  How do I tell Arch to boot from the USB instead?

If you need further info, just ask and I will update.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Arch that you want to tell to not from there, you need to let your BIOS know. Go into your boot settings and set it to boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot use gparted from within a system to resize. There are filesystems that you can resize on the fly like btrfs. You can copy your system to disk and copy it back onto a new partition scheme. Boot into from your bios.